# R first and last observations in data set

Tags: r, date, sequence

I have the following code:

```
df1<-data.frame(rep(sample(1:100,5),4),(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 20)),rep("A",20))
names(df1)<-c("ID","Date","Letter")
df2<-data.frame(df1$ID,(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'),   as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 20)),rep("B",20))
names(df2)<-c("ID","Date","Letter")
df3<-data.frame(df1$ID,(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'),    as.Date('2016/01/01'), by="day"), 20)),rep("C",20))
names(df3)<-c("ID","Date","Letter")
data<-rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

What I am trying to do is find the first date and the last date for each letter and ID

Therefore the outcome would be a four column dataframe with the first column the ID, the second column the Letter, the third column the first occurrence and the fourth column the last occurrence.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This sort of works, but not really: `aggregate(Date ~ ID + Letter, data, FUN = range)`. I'd suggest trying a package designed around nice syntax for grouped operations, like data.table or dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MIN <- aggregate(Date~ID+Letter, data, min)
MAX <- aggregate(Date~ID+Letter, data, max)
d <- merge(MIN, MAX, by = c("ID", "Letter"))
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much! I am new to R and I have been stuck on this problem for way too long. Just want I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(MINDate = min(Date), MAXDate = max(Date)), by = .(ID, Letter)]
```